# Need to find most common combination of letters

Tags: r

Let's say for simplicity that i have 10 rows of 5 characters where each character can be A-Z.

E.g//

```
KJGXI
GDGQT
JZKDC
YOTQD
SSDIQ
PLUWC
TORHC
PFJSQ
IIZMO
BRPOJ
WLMDX
AZDIJ
ARNUA
JEXGA
VFPIP
GXOXM
VIZEM
TFVQJ
OFNOG
QFNJR
ZGUBZ
CCTMB
HZPGV
ORQTJ
```

I want to know which 3 letter combination is most common. However, the combination does not need to be in order, nor next to each other. E.g

```
ABCXY
CQDBA

=ABC
```

I could probably brute-force it with endless loops but I was wondering if there was a better way of doing it!

Comment: Could you show us the brute-force method?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution:

```
x <- c("KJGXI", "GDGQT", "JZKDC", "YOTQD", "SSDIQ", "PLUWC", "TORHC", "PFJSQ", "IIZMO", "BRPOJ", "WLMDX", "AZDIJ",
       "ARNUA", "JEXGA", "VFPIP", "GXOXM", "VIZEM", "TFVQJ", "OFNOG", "QFNJR", "ZGUBZ", "CCTMB", "HZPGV", "ORQTJ")

temp <- do.call(cbind, lapply(strsplit(x, ""), combn, m = 3))

temp <- apply(temp, 2, sort)
temp <- apply(temp, 2, paste0, collapse = "")

sort(table(temp), decreasing = TRUE)
```

which will return the number of times each combination appear. You can then use `names(which.max(sort(table(temp), decreasing = TRUE)))` to have the combination (in this case, `"FJQ"`)

In this case, two combinations appear 3 times, you can do

```
result <- sort(table(temp), decreasing = TRUE)
names(which(result == max(result)))
# [1] "FJQ" "IMZ"
```

to have the two combinations which appear the most time.

---

The code works as follow:

- split each element of `x` in five letters, then generate each possible combination of 3 elements from the 5 letters
- sort each of those combination alphabetically
- paste the 3 letters together
- generate the count for each of those combinations, and sort the result

Answer (score 1):

I would split each string into letters, sort them, then use `combn` to get all combinations. Use `paste0` to collapse these back into strings and count.

```
txt <- c("KJGXI", "GDGQT", "JZKDC", "YOTQD", "SSDIQ", "PLUWC", "TORHC", 
     "PFJSQ", "IIZMO", "BRPOJ", "WLMDX", "AZDIJ", "ARNUA", "JEXGA", 
     "VFPIP", "GXOXM", "VIZEM", "TFVQJ", "OFNOG", "QFNJR", "ZGUBZ", 
     "CCTMB", "HZPGV", "ORQTJ")
txt2 <- strsplit(txt, split = "")

txt2 <- lapply(txt2, sort)
txt3 <- lapply(txt2, combn, m = 3)

txt4 <- lapply(txt3, function(x){apply(x, 2, paste0, collapse = "")})
table(unlist(txt4))
```

Several steps here could be combined.